# How to achieve to print string over bluetooth in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello I want to ask a question about Flutter:

I will develop an app for the company and we want to deploy our android app to Flutter, because it supports IOS. And our app includes bluetooth printer part. After smart device is connected to bluetooth, some part (receipt, information e.t.c) will be printed over bluetooth printer. It is possible to make with Flutter? Or does it have any alternatives for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with the help of plugins. If have a sdk to connect and print, use [Platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to integrate it in flutter.

If you are communication using Bluetooth directly, there are plugins available which you can give a try to.

Here are few plugins available:

- [Flutter Blue](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue)
- [Flutter Bluetooth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know Flutter blue plugin but dont flutter bluetooth plugin. I will try to write over bluetooth printer and i will give feedback. Also does it have any app or example about printing over bluetooth?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Printer apps. I've come across embedded projects using this.